# I have created EXCEL VSTO template with 2016 excel . I need to know how could I get UserName and Password of logged in User in the Excel Template

Tags: excel, templates, vsto

I have created Excel 2016 VSTO template.
[Open Visual studio and select the EXCEL VSTO TEMPLATE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMyMy.png)

Then I select the .xltx template
[Select the .xltx Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhwlD.png)

The project is created in the specified location with xltx Template.
[VSTO excel template Project location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtAvE.png)

Now if I open the template from the project location and go to the option.
you will see in the UserName place its getting the Default machine UserName
and its being Retrieved in the code. But I don't want it.
[Excel option General](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYZWu.png)

Now we will see that there is one more User is there that is logged in User.
[Logged In User need to retrieved in code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDvkn.jpg)

The code I am using to Retrieve the Logged In User.
[Code for retrieving the logged in User](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gH1F.png)

But in this code I am getting the user from Excel General Option area
but I want it from the Logged In Area.

Please tell me how to do it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Environment.UserName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.username?view=net-6.0) to get the user name of the current user.

I don't believe you can get the password.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I think you need to see the attached Image. I have put yellow mark for the logged in user denbhave@FujitsuAS.onmicrosoft.com. This username and related password I need to get in my Code for some functionality.

Comment: Can you post an example of the procedure in C# you're using?

Comment: I have Updated the My question please take a Glance.

Answer (score 0):

The Excel object model (nor VSTO) doesn't provide any property or method for that unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to get the Windows session password (string), only the user name using:

```
Environment.UserName
```

However, you can validate a password against the password of the Windows username using a routine like this:

```
public bool CheckUser(string userName, string password)
        {
            string domainName = System.Environment.UserDomainName;
            string domainUserName = System.Environment.UserName;
            bool answer = false;
            PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domainName, domainUserName, ContextOptions.Negotiate | ContextOptions.Signing | ContextOptions.Sealing);
            //PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domainName, domainUserName,ContextOptions.SecureSocketLayer | ContextOptions.Negotiate | ContextOptions.Signing | ContextOptions.Sealing);
            try
            {
                bool isValid = pc.ValidateCredentials(userName.ToUpper(), password);
                if (isValid)
                {
                    answer = true;
                    
                }
                else
                {
                    pc.Dispose();
                    
                    answer = false;
                    
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
            return answer;
        }
```